# How do I get all node objects from chef server in the form of json?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

I can use this command to return one node object from chef server:

```
knife node show -l --format=json <node_name>
```

I want to get all node objects (as json) to be able to write my own reports.

Is there a way to query the chef DB directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`knife search '*:*' --format=json` is probably more of what you want. Also check out `knife download nodes/` to get them as files.

Comment: Can I view the node objects directly on Chef server? are the json files just stored on the Chef Server's file system?

Comment: No, node data (and most other data) lives in a Postgres database. You should not talk to this database directly though as it is considered an internal component and can change at any time.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of unix pipe we can achieve this very easily.

Getting all the nodes names is easy

```
knife node list
```

Combine with some filter

```
knife node list | grep myhost
```

Get the node for all the hosts your are interested in

```
knife node list | grep myhost | xargs -n 1 knife node show -l -Fj
```

Comment: Is this the best way? It takes a super long time. I can't help but think a direct DB query would be much faster if that is possible. Are node objects stored in the DB as json or is that json object created dynamically by Chef server when it is returned to you when using that knife command?

Comment: You could use the `-P` option on xargs to do it in parallel i.e.
`xargs -n 1 -P 50`